# SPContext.Current.Web is not latest

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api

I am creating a list with a deployed list template. with the following code:

```
SPSite site = new SPSite("http://servername");
SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();

web.Lists.Add(listName, listName, listTemplate);
web.Update();
SPList List = Web.Lists[listName];
```

I am able to access the list with the `web` object which is used to create it. But, `SPContext.Current.Web` is not updated. So, the following throws error:

```
SPContext.Current.Web.Lists[listName]
```

Is it possible to update the `SPContext.Current` object with latest information so that the list accessible after it is created?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:** Code updated.

Comment: Are you sure both SPWeb refers to same location?

Comment: Yes. Both are referring to same location.

Comment: What is the error? Are you sure that it's the list not being found? Are you calling this from somewhere where SPContext.Current is not available (a receiver for instance).

Comment: Index out of range error. That means, list is not present in web.Lists.

Comment: Why not try `SPContext.Current.Web.Lists.Add(listName, listName, listTemplate);` since both `SPContext.Current.Web` and `web` are pointing to the same place anyway.

Comment: Yes, that's good idea but, creating the list is handled by class which accepts a URL of the web and the class which calls this method is operating on the current web. This behavior of both the classes is justifiable. Moreover, I have already written so much of code and now, it is little time consuming to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the below line after `web.Update()` and it started working.

```
SPContext myContext = SPContext.GetContext(Web);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't show this, so I'm going to ask for the obvious: did you try calling [web.Update()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.update.aspx) right after adding the new list?

Comment: Yes. I did that and got the same behavior. I've updated the question with this code.